# Python/Pyside: Own QFileIconProvider implementation fails with no exceptions thrown

Tags: python, pyside, qfile

I tried to create my own `QFileIconProvider` class, which I want to use for a `QFileSystemModel`. 
I ended up with this code:

```
class SeIconProvider(QtGui.QFileIconProvider):

def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QFileIconProvider.__init__(self)

    self.rsFileIcon = QtGui.QIcon(':images/rs-file.png')
    self.otherFileIcon = QtGui.QIcon(':images/newfile.png')
    self.folderIcon = QtGui.QIcon(':images/openFolder.png')

def icon(self, type):
    if type == self.File:
        return self.rsFileIcon
    if type == self.Folder:
        return self.folderIcon

    return self.otherFileIcon

def icon(self, info):
    if info.isFile():
        return self.otherFileIcon
    if info.isDir():
        return self.folderIcon
    return self.otherFileIcon

def type(self, info):
    if info.isDir():
        return 'Directory'
    return 'File'

class FolderView(QtGui.QTreeView):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self)

        self.createComponents()
        self.createLayout()

    def createComponents(self):
        self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setIconProvider(SeIconProvider())
        self.setModel(self.model)

    def createLayout(self):
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
```

Now my problem is that not only no icons are displayed in the treeview, but the code doesn't throw any exceptions. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself now....kinda :D

I used to go another way and wrote my own QFileSystemModel class. Then i have overwritten the data method and returned my own Icons. My code looks like the following:

```
class SeFileSystemModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel):

def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QFileSystemModel.__init__(self)
    self.fileEndPattern = re.compile("^.*\.(\w{2,4})$")

def data(self, index, role):
    if index.column() == 0 and role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
        if self.fileEndPattern.match(index.data()) is not None:
            if index.data().endswith('rs'):
                return QtGui.QIcon(':icons/rs-file.png')
            return QtGui.QIcon(':icons/newfile.png')

        return QtGui.QIcon(':icons/openFolder.png')

    return super(SeFileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)

class FolderView(QtGui.QTreeView):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self)

        self.createComponents()

    def createComponents(self):
        self.model = SeFileSystemModel()
        self.setModel(self.model)
```

If anyone knows, why my original code wasn't working, I would still be very thankful about an answer :)